# PHP FFmpeg, upload video and let user select start and end offsets to trim the video

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

This is what I need to do:

1. User goes to the HTML web app (works on desktop and mobile)
2. Uploads a video (depending on phone recording and bitrate, could be 100mb)
3. Use FFMPEG to trim the video to 15 seconds only.

Now for the 3rd part we need to let the user select the start and end offsets for the trimming. Maybe extract scenes and let them select?

Please help. Thanks in advance.